# How to remove these ajax popup urls?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Due to some programming errors, I got thousands of popup url created dynamically, now I want to remove permanently without disturbing running functionalists on website www.wedddingplz.com.

For example - `http://www.weddingplz.com/delhi-ncr/Beauty-Parlours/Aaina-Hair-Colour-Salon-Janakpuri is popup url on button Send Enquiry of page http://www.weddingplz.com/delhi-ncr/Beauty-Parlours/Aaina-Hair-Colour-Salon-Janakpuri`

This website is created in PHP Zend, provide easiest method to clean these urls.
Few more examples are -

```
weddingplz.com/detail/quickquotepopup/id/9359/zone_id/7
weddingplz.com/detail/quickquotepopup/id/9361/zone_id/9
weddingplz.com/detail/quickquotepopup/id/9364/zone_id/7
weddingplz.com/search/contactform/vendorid/10013/category/Travel+Agents/category_id/32/name/Jyoti+Travels+Pvt.+Ltd./zone_id/7
weddingplz.com/search/contactform/vendorid/10014/category/Travel+Agents/category_id/32/name/K+R+Sankaran+Tours/zone_id/1
weddingplz.com/search/contactform/vendorid/10016/category/Travel+Agents/category_id/32/name/K+L+Tours+and+Travels/zone_id/7
weddingplz.com/search/morebranches/vendorid/3396/catName/Confectionary-and-Chocolates
weddingplz.com/search/morebranches/vendorid/3441/catName/Confectionary-and-Chocolates
weddingplz.com/search/morebranches/vendorid/3445/catName/Confectionary-and-Chocolates
weddingplz.com/search/morebranches/vendorid/8910/catName/Spa
weddingplz.com/search/morebranches/vendorid/8921/catName/Spa
weddingplz.com/search/morebranches/vendorid/8924/catName/Spa
```

etc...

Thanks

Comment: Remove whatever is causing the pop-up? `window.alert()`?

Comment: Remove all the `.popup()` calls?